# MySQL - count where id contained in a string

Tags: mysql, sql, search, longtext

My table is called "asd"

I have this schema:

```
id        |  date     |  content |
AUTO_INC    DATETIME    LONGTEXT
```

now assuming `content = 45,67,89,3,45,5`

how do i `search COUNT()` in this table `WHERE content CONTAINS 89` for example ?

i tryed `SELECT COUNT() FROM asd WHERE content IN(89);` but i got no results.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just use [FIND_IN_SET](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `table` WHERE FIND_IN_SET(89,`content`);
```

P.S. You need to read about many-to-many relations.

Comment: this is exactly what i need i think, need just to test it +1

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM   ASD
WHERE ',' + content  + ','  like '%,89,%'
```

Answer (score 1):

can you please try like this....i have seen something you want in this link http://www.randomsnippets.com/2008/10/05/how-to-count-values-with-mysql-queries/
..hope it helps

```
  SELECT SUM(IF(content = 89, 1,0)) AS `MATCHED VALUE`,
    COUNT(content) AS `total`
    FROM asd
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM   ASD
WHERE  content LIKE '%,89,%' OR
       content LIKE '%,89' OR
       content LIKE '89,%'
```

`%,89,%` - to match 89 in the middle of the content

`%,89` - at the end of the content

`89,%` - at the beginning of the content

Comment: no this will count **,890** too, i need to count where it is exactly 89

Comment: No, it will not, I have `,`. 890 does not match any of `,89,` or `,89<end-of-line>` or `<start-of-line>89,`

Comment: uhmmmm not sure about mmmm

Comment: 890 can be matched by `89%` or `,89%` or `%89%` for example, but not with `,` specified.

Comment: will this work also with my set 45,67,89,3,45,5 ? what if need 5 instead of 89 it's same query ?

Comment: Yes, it will. To match `5` use: `%,5,%`, `%,5` and `5,%`

Comment: if no other solution i'll accept your answer thx!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt FROM `asd` WHERE `content` LIKE '%,89,%' OR  `content` LIKE '89,%' OR `content` LIKE '%,89';
```

Check the SQL Fiddle :  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/151c7/2/0